# How do I clone a local repo with submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-clone

Say I recursively clone a repo.

```
$ git clone --recursive ssh://server/project/client
Cloning into 'client'...
remote: Counting objects: 191, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (191/191)
remote: Total 191 (delta 53), reused 159 (delta 53)
Receiving objects: 100% (191/191), 27.59 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (53/53), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule 'gui' (ssh://server/project/client/gui.git) registered for path 'gui'
Cloning into 'gui'...
remote: Counting objects: 3213, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (3213/3213)
remote: Total 3213 (delta 1272), reused 3107 (delta 1272)
Receiving objects: 100% (3213/3213), 47.88 MiB | 12.05 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1272/1272), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'gui': checked out '7315db8d7a8b36929f7874dc5477359839ec51ce'
```

Now I want to create a local clone of that local repo (perhaps after making and committing changes locally).

```
$ git clone --recursive client/ client_copy
Cloning into 'client_copy'...
done.
Submodule 'gui' (/home/deployer/client/gui.git) registered for path 'gui'
fatal: repository '/home/deployer/client/gui.git' does not exist
Clone of '/home/deployer/client/gui.git' into submodule path 'gui' failed
```

My `.gitmodules` file looks like this:

```
[submodule "gui"]
        path = gui
        url = ../client/gui.git
```

Why does this fail, and how can I address the issue?

Comment: You should probably clone a bare repository, or create one first, push the contents of the normal repository there, and then clone the bare repository.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala is that a hack, or is that the idiomatic way of handling local repositories in git? it seems needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with your `.gitmodules` file. The submodule `url` in your project is defined as a relative path from the superproject repository, but when the submodules are cloned, they are placed using the `path` location.

In other words, git is trying to pull the submodules from the `url` location, but on your local machine, they're actually at the `path` location.

To fix this, clone just the local superproject repository (`git clone /path/to/superproject`), then go into the new clone's `.gitsubmodules` and change the `url`s to be `./<whatever-the-path-is>`. For example, your gui submodule would become:

```
[submodule "gui"]
        path = gui
        url = ./gui
```

Change each submodule in `.gitmodules` to be like this, then run:

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

and that should do it!

Answer (score 1):

I needed a more comprehensive solution than this, due to the strange way gitlab clones things (SRC is toplevel source repo folder and DST is the requested toplevel destination folder):

```
git clone $SRC $DST
MODULES=$(git -C $SRC config --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp url)
for MODULE in ${MODULES}; do
    MODULE_PATH=$(git -C $SRC config ${MODULE});
    git -C $DST config ${MODULE} ${MODULE_PATH};
done
git -C $DST submodule update --init --recursive;
```

It would be great if there were a built-in way to do this though...

Comment: Nice.  It clones the submodules from their origin though.  I used this as a basis for a script to clone the submodules from the locally cloned submodules.

Comment: In my particular case I was working in a gitlab build environment, so I want to use the actual url (the local folders are empty).  I have another version of this that I use that works off the local folders, in that case I use this: `MODULE_PATH=$SRC/$(git -C $SRC config --file=.gitmodules ${MODULE})` where I grab "--get-regexp path" instead of url.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to clone the submodules from the locally cloned submodules, I come to the version below.  This allows for only one level of submodules.

```
git clone $src $dst
modules=$(git -C $src config --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp url)
for module in $modules; do
  module_path=$(git -C $src config --file .gitmodules ${module%.url}.path)
  git -C $dst config ${module} $src/$module_path
done
git -C $dst submodule update --init
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: with Git 2.12 or less, this `git submodule update --init --recursive` can fail because of some unusual path of the submodules.
This is fixed in Git 2.13 (Q2 2017)

See [commit cf9e55f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf9e55f49438d07dd554c5ade92f1c266363af36) (07 Apr 2017) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5bceab4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bceab4113f89eb29d0a737961f43135bf83d2d9), 24 Apr 2017)</sup>

> ### `submodule`: prevent backslash expansion in submodule names
>
> When attempting to add a submodule with backslashes in its name '`git submodule`' fails in a funny way.  We can see that some of the
>   backslashes are expanded resulting in a bogus path:

```
git -C main submodule add ../sub\\with\\backslash
fatal: repository '/tmp/test/sub\witackslash' does not exist
fatal: clone of '/tmp/test/sub\witackslash' into submodule path
```

> To solve this, convert calls to '`read`' to '`read -r`' in [`git-submodule.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf9e55f49438d07dd554c5ade92f1c266363af36/git-submodule.sh#L335) in order to prevent backslash expansion in submodule names.