# Cloning a local repository with submodules that is tracking a remote repo

Tags: git, git-clone

Our compilation model consists on a super-project with 200 subprojects. My local copy tracks our development (remote) server.

I need to make a clean clone of the super-project but I'm bandwidth limited as to fetch all that info from remote server (last time I did it it took almost 7 hours to complete).

(_Note: the reason why I need a clean copy and not just a new branch on current checked out copy, is because I have to make a huge change in many projects and I want to get rid of all the binary files generated during compilation to be sure the projects are compiling correctly, at the time I don't lose current compilation for normal development).

I've read [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38210572/1485885), so I've:

```
git init new_copy
cd new_copy
git remote add origin file:///c/local_copy
git fetch
git checkout develop
git submodule init
```

So far everything is OK, but I noticed that submodules were still tracking the remote origin. So, as cited answer mentioned, I'd have to manually change the `.gitmodules` file to track the local copy instead. As I said, we have 200 subproject and, in addition, the URL for each submodule repository not necessarily have a pattern, as to make a simple replacement:

**Sample of `.gitmodules`**

```
[submodule "libs/lib1"]
    path = libs/lib1
    url = https://our-remote-server/library1.git
[submodule "istallers/installer1"]
    path = installers/installer1
    url = https://our-remote-server/the_first_installer.git
[submodule "installers/installer2"]
    path = installers/installer2
    url = https://our-remote-server/installer2.git
[submodule "apps/a_great_app"]
    path = apps/a_great_app
    url = https://our-remote-server/foobar.git
```

As far I've understood, I have to change the `.gitmodules` of the *cloned* repo to something like this in order to track local copies:

```
[submodule "libs/lib1"]
    path = libs/lib1
    url = file:///c/local_copy/libs/lib1
[submodule "istallers/installer1"]
    path = installers/installer1
    url = file:///c/local_copy/installers/installer1
[submodule "installers/installer2"]
    path = installers/installer2
    url = file:///c/local_copy/installers/installer2
[submodule "apps/a_great_app"]
    path = apps/a_great_app
    url = file:///c/local_copy/apps/a_great_app
```

I only need it for the initial clone, later I can restore the `.gitmodules` so it can track the remote origin back again.

Is there any standard / official / easy way to do it or do I have to make a script to generate the new `.gitmodules` files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the `submodule foreach` statement? It applies a git command to each submodule in your gitmodules.

Check this as reference: [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very fluent with git yet, may you develop a bit your answer please?

Comment: The way to apply some changes to each submodule is the foreach command. Writing `git submodule foreach [any git command]` will apply the git command to each submodule. In that way you can change the URL of the modules, the only issue here that I can't really solve is how to generate the new url since there is no pattern.

Comment: Yes, the basic usage of `git submodule foreach` is known to me, but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question yet, that is, precisely, how to solve the URL generation problem

Comment: If there is no pattern about the URLs, as you said, I guess you need to write them somewhere, then you can write a simple script that reads each URL and launch the related git command with the last as parameter. In this way you don't even need to use the foreach